# in a J2EE application when does a listener get called?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I have a J2EE app and it has a listener in `web.xml`.

Listener contains a method called `contextInitialized`

I want to know when does `contextInitialized` actually get called?

From my reading I understand that it gets called when deploying the application.  Can there be situations/scenario's where it could be called after the application has been deployed?  Say that I am in a Clustered GlassFish app server environment.  Could it be called after the application has been deployed?

Answer (score 2):

It's called once when the application is first deployed. It shouldn't get called again if the application stays deployed.

However, the application may go through the undeploy/deploy cycle while the server is running. For example, you can set it up so that the application is redeployed when a file is changed in the directory.

Comment: Exactly, from the [API doc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html): *Notification that the web application initialization process is starting.*

Comment: In this case, the listener is called only at the time of deployment because the method is contextInitialized(). However, in general, a listener is called whenever an event for which it is "listening" occurs. Is this understanding right?